# How can I run the command: "code ." from MacOS terminal after VS Code installation

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, macos-high-sierra

I keep getting this error when I run: `code .` on MacOS terminal

`-bash: code: command not found`

[-bash: code: command not found image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuZIK.jpg)

Comment: Does [How to Open Applications Using Terminal on Mac](https://www.wikihow.com/Open-Applications-Using-Terminal-on-Mac) help?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton. I recently started using Mac. On Windows PC when I install VS Code, I can automatically open it via the terminal by typing `code .` I installed VS Code on my Mac and the ran the command `code .` on terminal but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the [*launching-from-the-command-line*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line) section of VS Code official documentation answers this question.

**Steps**

1. Launch VS Code
2. Open the **Command Palette** (F1) and type 'shell command' to find the **Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH** command.
3. Restart the terminal for the new $PATH value to take effect. You'll be able to type 'code .' in any folder to start editing files in that folder.

Comment: Can you please outline the steps that solved this here in the answer? If the linked page disappears or changes, your answer will no longer be usable by other people having the same question...